# LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol when using qwt plot in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qwt

I am subclassing **QwtPlot**. I have the following error:

**moc_myplot.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QwtPlot::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QwtPlot@@2UQMetaObject@@B)**
I have tried to the following things: run qmake, rebuild, clean, delete debug folder, recompile qwt library. That doesn't help. Here is minimal code:
myplot.h:

```
#ifndef MYPLOT_H
#define MYPLOT_H
#include <QObject>
#include <qwt_plot.h>

class MyPlot : public QwtPlot
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyPlot();
};

#endif // MYPLOT_H
```

myplot.cpp:

```
#include "myplot.h"

MyPlot::MyPlot()
{

}
```

Here is **.pro** file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-06-22T19:33:24
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyPlot
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    myplot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    myplot.h

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/lib/ -lqwt
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/lib/ -lqwtd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/lib/ -lqwt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/include
```

I am using Qt Creator 3.4.1 Based on Qt 5.4.2 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit). Kit: **Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit**. Compiler: **Microsof Visual C++ Compiler 12.0(amd64)**. If I comment `Q_OBJECT` macro in `myplot.h` everything is ok. I can use `qwt_plot` without subclassing, so that `this->setCentralWidget(new QwtPlot());` line in `mainwindow.cpp` is ok.

Comment: Did you look in the documentation to see what the requirements of using `Q_OBJECT` are?

Comment: The QwtPlot methods seem to be missing.  Do you know for certain which library defines them and that you have specified to link to that lib?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious of course. MyPlot class contains several signals and slots. I have deleted them in that example code.

Comment: Did you recreate the makefile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this is an old [issue](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32028-unresolved-external-symbol-quot-public-static-struct-QMetaObject-const-QwtPlot-staticMe) that was present in at least version 4.6.

The workaround is basically a preprocessor define of `QWT_DLL` from the "very lowest library that calls QWT".

Comment: I have added `DEFINES += QWT_DLL` line into `.pro` file. It works!